# Aligned and unaligned loading and storing of SSE vectors - how to reduce code duplication?

Tags: c++, sse, simd

Often  I am forced to write two implementations of function which used SSE instructions because input and output buffers may have aligned or not aligned addresses:

```
void some_function_aligned(const float * src, size_t size, float * dst)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 4)
    {
        __m128 a = _mm_load_ps(src + i);
        // do something...
        _mm_store_ps(dst + i, a);
    }
}
```

and

```
void some_function_unaligned(const float * src, size_t size, float * dst)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 4)
    {
        __m128 a = _mm_loadu_ps(src + i);
        // do something...
        _mm_storeu_ps(dst + i, a);
    }
}
```

And there is a question: How to reduce code duplication, because these functions are almost equal?

Comment: Don't worry about alignment on newer processors. After the nehalem series (i series) alignment has less of an impact than it did previously and using the unaligned instructions with aligned data has no penalty. For example MSVC 2013 will not issue the aligned instructions (even if you use the aligned intrinsic)

Comment: I know it, but there are CPUs older than Nehalem. And I am forced to support them in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a solution of this problem which widely used here (http://simd.sourceforge.net/).
It is based on the specialization of template functions for loading and saving of SSE vectors:

```
template <bool align> __m128 load(const float * p);

template <> inline __m128 load<false>(const float * p)
{
    return _mm_loadu_ps(p); 
}

template <> inline __m128 load<true>(const float * p)
{
    return _mm_load_ps(p); 
}

template <bool align> void store(float  * p, __m128 a);

template <> inline void Store<false>(float  * p, __m128 a)
{
    _mm_storeu_ps(p, a);
}

template <> inline void Store<true>(float  * p, __m128 a)
{
    _mm_store_ps(p, a);
}
```

And now we can write only one implementation of template function:

```
template <bool align> void some_function(const float * src, size_t size, float * dst)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 4)
    {
        __m128 a = load<align>(src + i);
        // do something...
        store<align>(dst + i, a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a useful technique. You can also do something similar for C code, where you just use inline functions and then "specialise" via hard-coded function parameters (the compiler optimises away the branches).